# Best class to keep track of a fictional date in time? (Java)

Tags: java, date

I'm making a video game in Java and I ran into a problem where I need date to be managed accurately. The game will start off somewhere in 2010 and it needs to continue on day after day following the Gregorian calendar. I won't be using hours or minutes whatsoever so the only important thing to me is that after telling my program to go one day into the future, it needs to correctly know that February has only 28 days and that December has 31 days, etc.

I know there is a Java Date class but I did NOT see any kind of 'go X dates' method in the API (the reason that's not there is beyond me). There is a set date feature but that won't work for me as my program won't be sure which months have less/more days, etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) if you're still using Java 7 or earlier (in which case you should *also* be looking to move to Java 8), or the `java.time` package if you're using Java 8.

In both cases, you want the `LocalDate` class, which is used to represent a date without a time, and without any associated time zone.

It's a *much, much* cleaner API to use than the antiquated and *horrible* `java.util.Calendar` (or `java.util.Date`). No bizarre constants to worry about instead of simple method calls, no 0-based months etc.

You can just use:

```
date = date.plusDays(1);
```

to advance the date. Great!

Comment: You gotta go vintage. It's all the rage these days.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am currently using Java 8. Thus you would recommend LocalDate over JodaTime?

Comment: @Hatefiend: It's LocalDate in both - but yes, if you're using Java 8, I'd use java.time.

Comment: Could you give some more info as to why you categorize the java.util.Calendar API as horrible?

Comment: @ryanbwork: It would take too long. It's not quite as bad as java.util.Date, but still *horribly* easy to misuse, hard to use well, unintuitive (who thought 0-based months were a good idea?), and mutable. And misnamed. And it doesn't represent what the OP wants to represent, which is just a date, without time or time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet Would local date have the capability to make certain events happen on a certain upcoming date? Obviously I'd have to sort all that out but would localdate be a good host for such logic or would I be better off with calendar?

Comment: @Hatefiend: What do you mean by "make certain events happen"? It doesn't "make things happen" - it's just a date.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using java 7-, the [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class provides an [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) method which you could utilize to increment the day/month/year/etc by any amount you'd like. Here's an example which adds 5 days to a given calendar instance:

```
mycal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
```

If you're using java 8+, or have the ability to include Joda time in your environment, see Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: Or the OP could join the 21st century and use a decent API :)

Comment: @JonSkeet agree, though there are some environments where utilizing non-standard libraries (or even compiling and running on java 8) is not an option

Comment: If the question had *stated* that (and given a really good reason for it - I hear a lot of *bad* reasons, which should be pushed back against) then it would be reasonable.... but `java.util.Calendar` should be a *last* option, not the first thing you reach for.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of Java version , I would use Calendar . I would not rely on 3rd party jar for dates when JDK provides the solution.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CalendarArithmatic
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2010,Calendar.FEBRUARY,28);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // add 1 day 
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
String date=sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(date);

// prints: 
// 2010-March-01
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add "dates" or days to your date, you can use Calendar (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for that:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```